# Creating Mysql query with GROUP_CONCAT, twee left joins, WHERE LIKE clause and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, where-clause

I'm having a problem with creating a `mysql` query. I have the following tables: `objects, object_photos, photos`

`objects` contains: `id, street, etc..`

`object_photos` contains: `object_id, photo_id, sort_index`

`photos` contains: `id, file, etc...`

I need to get the objects with streetname likely be 'term', get the photos belonging to that object, put those photos as an sub-array of the object.

If it's possible, I want a typo to be forgiven, if it's too hard to do, no problem, i'll use `WHERE objects.street LIKE %term%` and tell people to type a part of the streetname.
Also, I'm having trouble sorting the photos by a `sort_index` and limiting those photos to 1

With googling, reading etc, I came with a query:

```
SELECT objects.id, object.street,
GROUP_CONCAT(photos.file) AS photo
FROM objects
LEFT JOIN object_photos
ON object_photos.object_id=objects.id
LEFT JOIN photos
ON photos.id=object_photos.photo_id
GROUP BY objects.id'
```

I'm not understanding `GROUP BY` in this query and this one is missing a few clauses I need mentioned above.

I hope you people can help me!

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` is an aggregate function that creates a list with a separator. If you `GROUP BY objects.id` your result will be one row per `objects.id`, and the `GROUP_CONCAT` value will be a list of `photo.file` for each `objects.id`. Try it without `GROUP BY` and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need left joins.  A better practice would be to GROUP BY your SELECT fields that are aggregate functions.

```
SELECT objects.id, object.street, GROUP_CONCAT(photos.file ORDER BY sort_index) AS photo 
FROM objects 
JOIN object_photos 
  ON object_photos.object_id=objects.id 
JOIN photos 
  ON photos.id=object_photos.photo_id
WHERE object.street LIKE '%term%'
GROUP BY objects.id, objects.street
```

I did not understand your "limit those photos to 1" request.  Could you share some sample data and expected output

Comment: Thanks you very much! It works! ;)
With "limit those those photos to 1" I mean I only need 1 photo, e.g. for a thumbnail.
Why do you GROUP BY id and street? If I leave out 'objects.street', it gives the same result.